# VLC Updater always shows me a new update to v3.0.0 64 bit

Tags: windows, windows-10, 64-bit, vlc-media-player

The `VLC Updater` is showing on every windows startup that there's a new version `v3.0.0 64bit`.

Uninstall and/or reinstall does not solve the problem. Anyone got a solution for this behavior?

My installed version is `vlc-3.0.0-win64.exe`.

My System is:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Version 1709
- Build 16299.192

[image: VLC]

[image: programs and features]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstalling the `VLC Updater` solved the problem. `VLC media player` is also checking for updates itself.